# How do I set up Netbeans to work with Play Framework 2.0 easily

Tags: java, netbeans, playframework-2.0

As a Netbeans user, how do I edit my Play 2.0 applications in Netbeans in a way that is simple, and all the classes are recognized and not underlined in red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much easier way.

1. Download and Install Play Framework 2.0
2. Into the command line:
       
         

         `play new <application-name>

         cd <application-name>

         play eclipsify`
3. Open Netbeans
4. From the netbeans menu, select:
     `File > Import Project > Eclipse Project > Import project ignoring dependencies`
5. Copy and paste your project folder location the same into both text boxes

**Tips:**

1. Do not compile, build, or anything between creating the project and importing it.
2. In your play Controllers, Netbeans will not recognize your new views if the play server is not running. You can also the commandline and type: `play compile` to force the views to be compiled.

Comment: Somehow this options dose not seem to work for me. NetBeans tells me that my project folder is not a valid Eclipse workspace. The output form the `eclipsify` command is following: `[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
[info] myApp` - Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: I just reinstalled, so I don't have it with me, but don't confuse a  workspace and a project. A workspace contains projects - like a parent folder. Make sure you select the correct one from the Netbeans import dialog. Comment again if you're still having problems.

Comment: After running `eclipsify` on my project, I go to `Import->Eclipse Project`, choose my Play project and then I get the following error: http://cl.ly/image/361D0D2E2d2Q

Comment: Use import project ignoring dependencies. Make the Project to Import and the Destination folder the same. This will turn the eclipse project into an eclipse and netbeans project in the same folder.

Comment: Oh, and if they go out of sync. You can always clean and build again, and select File > Import > Resync Eclipse Project

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much! Maybe you could add this to your answer. I had an existing project, ran `play clean` then `play eclipsify` and then imported the project the way you mentioned above and that worked just fine!